# How do you create a custom Akka .NET logger?

Tags: logging, akka.net

The Akka .NET documentation explains only how to [configure custom loggers](http://getakka.net/docs/Logging#configuring-custom-loggers). How do you go about developing a custom logger in the first place?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've spent some time researching how to do this, and wrote up a detailed [blog post](http://gigi.nullneuron.net/gigilabs/custom-loggers-in-akka-net/) about it.

In a nutshell, you need to handle five messages: `Debug`, `Info`, `Warning`, `Error`, and `InitializeLogger`.

```
public class MyLogger : ReceiveActor
{
    public MyLogger()
    {
        Receive<Debug>(e => this.Log(LogLevel.DebugLevel, e.ToString()));
        Receive<Info>(e => this.Log(LogLevel.InfoLevel, e.ToString()));
        Receive<Warning>(e => this.Log(LogLevel.WarningLevel, e.ToString()));
        Receive<Error>(e => this.Log(LogLevel.ErrorLevel, e.ToString()));
        Receive<InitializeLogger>(_ => Sender.Tell(new LoggerInitialized()));
    }

    // ...
}
```

The first four messages are self-explanatory if you've ever used logging before.

`Log()` is just a helper function defined by you, that handles the details of logging the message to destination.

`InitializeLogger` is done at startup. It is needed to notify the internal event bus that the logger has been set up and is ready to start receiving messages. You must reply with a `LoggerInitialized` message.

Ideally you should also take care of allocation and cleanup of external resources using the appropriate lifecyle hooks (`PreStart()` and `PostStop()`). Logging adapters out there don't currently do this yet.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you just need a regular Actor that overrides OnReceive(object message). Here is the default logger implementation:

https://github.com/akkadotnet/akka.net/blob/4acfa7c363bfa83ac71849a5a8487c8d6b1bbcb1/src/core/Akka/Event/DefaultLogger.cs

Here is the trace logger implementation:

https://github.com/akkadotnet/akka.net/blob/92177da15a7ef54e23b5224c05997592cbceb8e4/src/core/Akka/Event/TraceLogger.cs